# If someone commits an Internet crime using your Wi-Fi, how can you legally prove it wasn't you?

Tags: criminal-law, internet

Let's say for the sake of example, you're an 18 year old college student and your uncle's family comes over to visit. Your cousins ask for your Wi-Fi password and you give it to them, or they guess the password because it's too easy. Hypothetically, if one of them commits some sort of Internet crime, such as bullying or sexting or something else and 3 years later the police discovers it and you get sued, how can you legally prove it wasn't you behind the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to prove it wasn't you: they have to prove it *was*. That's what proof beyond reasonable doubt means.

BTW, the police don't sue you (unless you break a contract with them) they prosecute you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127184/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-if-someone-commits-an-internet-crime-using-your-w).